# Corrupted /etc/adduser.conf

Tags: adduser

My /etc/adduser.conf file got corrupted:

```
$ less /etc/adduser.conf
"/etc/adduser.conf" may be a binary file.  See it anyway?
```

How can I reinstall a fresh copy?

Comment: Oh and of course a warning: if you do not know WHY this happend assume the worst ...

Comment: Rather than blindly replacing the file you should've seen what's inside that "corrupted" file, whether it was an accident or something more shady like an attacker doing mischief.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There appears to be a 'clean' copy in the `/usr/share/adduser/` directory:

```
$ diff -s /usr/share/adduser/adduser.conf /etc/adduser.conf 
Files /usr/share/adduser/adduser.conf and /etc/adduser.conf are identical
```

so you should be able to simply replace the corrupted one with that

```
sudo cp /usr/share/adduser/adduser.conf /etc/adduser.conf
```

Answer (score 6):

Permissions:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2975 2009-02-12 08:09 /etc/adduser.conf
```

And this is the default content (copy/paste and recreate it):

```
# /etc/adduser.conf: `adduser' configuration.
# See adduser(8) and adduser.conf(5) for full documentation.

# The DSHELL variable specifies the default login shell on your
# system.
DSHELL=/bin/bash

# The DHOME variable specifies the directory containing users' home
# directories.
DHOME=/home

# If GROUPHOMES is "yes", then the home directories will be created as
# /home/groupname/user.
GROUPHOMES=no

# If LETTERHOMES is "yes", then the created home directories will have
# an extra directory - the first letter of the user name. For example:
# /home/u/user.
LETTERHOMES=no

# The SKEL variable specifies the directory containing "skeletal" user
# files; in other words, files such as a sample .profile that will be
# copied to the new user's home directory when it is created.
SKEL=/etc/skel

# FIRST_SYSTEM_[GU]ID to LAST_SYSTEM_[GU]ID inclusive is the range for UIDs
# for dynamically allocated administrative and system accounts/groups.
# Please note that system software, such as the users allocated by the base-passwd
# package, may assume that UIDs less than 100 are unallocated.
FIRST_SYSTEM_UID=100
LAST_SYSTEM_UID=999

FIRST_SYSTEM_GID=100
LAST_SYSTEM_GID=999

# FIRST_[GU]ID to LAST_[GU]ID inclusive is the range of UIDs of dynamically
# allocated user accounts/groups.
FIRST_UID=1000
LAST_UID=29999

FIRST_GID=1000
LAST_GID=29999

# The USERGROUPS variable can be either "yes" or "no".  If "yes" each
# created user will be given their own group to use as a default.  If
# "no", each created user will be placed in the group whose gid is
# USERS_GID (see below).
USERGROUPS=yes

# If USERGROUPS is "no", then USERS_GID should be the GID of the group
# `users' (or the equivalent group) on your system.
USERS_GID=100

# If DIR_MODE is set, directories will be created with the specified
# mode. Otherwise the default mode 0755 will be used.
DIR_MODE=0755

# If SETGID_HOME is "yes" home directories for users with their own
# group the setgid bit will be set. This was the default for
# versions << 3.13 of adduser. Because it has some bad side effects we
# no longer do this per default. If you want it nevertheless you can
# still set it here.
SETGID_HOME=no

# If QUOTAUSER is set, a default quota will be set from that user with
# `edquota -p QUOTAUSER newuser'
QUOTAUSER=""

# If SKEL_IGNORE_REGEX is set, adduser will ignore files matching this
# regular expression when creating a new home directory
SKEL_IGNORE_REGEX="dpkg-(old|new|dist)"

# Set this if you want the --add_extra_groups option to adduser to add
# new users to other groups.
# This is the list of groups that new non-system users will be added to
# Default:
#EXTRA_GROUPS="dialout cdrom floppy audio video plugdev users"

# If ADD_EXTRA_GROUPS is set to something non-zero, the EXTRA_GROUPS
# option above will be default behavior for adding new, non-system users
#ADD_EXTRA_GROUPS=1


# check user and group names also against this regular expression.
#NAME_REGEX="^[a-z][-a-z0-9]*\$"
```

Comment: I wish I could select 2 right answers. Both of these answers seem perfectly valid to me. Thank you.

Comment: Oh I don't mind ;) His is the better method since you get a 100% uncomprimised version that stands against time. Mine might become invalid when they change defaults. An upvote is more than enough and @steeldriver needs the rep since he is still under 20k ;)